# Self referencing (1:1) a table in Entity Framework code first model

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to self reference a table in my model to get a couple of details for my `User` entity

I have a class that looks like:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Column("recid")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("givenname")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Column("sn")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Column("mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Column("managerEmail")]
    public string LineManagerEmail { get; set; }

    public string LineManagerFirstName { get; set; }

    public string LineManagerLastName { get; set; }
}
```

How can I map this so that when returning a `User` the `LineManagerFirstName` and `LineManagerLastName` is retrieved from the same table, joined on LineManagerEmail?

for example, I anticipate the SQL to be something like:

```
SELECT
  user.recid,
  user.givenName,
  user.sn,
  user.mail,
  user.managerEmail,
  manager.givenName as lineManagerFirstName,
  manager.givenName as lineManagerLastName,
FROM user
INNER JOIN user AS manager 
ON user.managerEmail = manager.mail
```

In my Context class, I know I'll need to override the OnModelCreating method:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().
    }
```

...but being new to EF, this is where I'm getting a bit stuck!

Comment: It's much easier to expose `public User Manager {get;set;}` object then so you would go user.Manager.FirstName in your code, as well as user.Manager.Email.

Comment: Also, if you are using code first, why do you create such weird names for your columns? If you ever need to write sql queries in your database (brobably you will) then `givenname` and `sn` will be harder to remember than `FirstName` and `LastName` which is what EF would generate for you.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified - this is an existing database (with the weird column names)

Comment: Ok, so the table you have already contains the managerEmail, but  you want the first and last name of the manager? I would still probably try to load the complete User object as the manager, based on its `Mail` property being equal to `managerEmail`.

Comment: hmm, i was trying to avoid loading the whole user object if possible...
I guess i *could* create a view as per my above SQL and map that.. seems like I'm doing things twice there though

Comment: If you do so, you will probably not be able to update users as a view is readonly. You should create entities according to tables and then query according to your needs and materialize a UserExtended with a query like `from u in Users select new UserExtended { ... LineManagerFirstName = u.Manager.FirstName...}`

Comment: Yeah, I will go down that path (entities to tables, then 'User' DTO objects that get returned to the client)

Comment: So i guess my question is now more how to join on the email, rather than primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a view, you will probably not be able to update users as a view is readonly.

You should create entities according to tables and then query according to your needs and materialize a UserExtended with a query like

```
var q = from 
            u in Users 
        select 
            new UserExtended { 
                Id = u.Id,
                /* .... */
                LineManagerFirstName = u.Manager.FirstName
                /* .... */
            }
```

or a more elaborated query, in case of self join without the PK.

```
var q = 
    from u in Users
    join m in Users on u.Email equals m.Email
select 
    new UserExtended { 
        Id = u.Id,
        /* .... */
        LineManagerFirstName = m.FirstName
        /* .... */
    }
```

will give you the following SQL (fields name do not match as I use one of my schema)

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[idUtilisateur] AS [idUtilisateur], 
    [Extent2].[Email] AS [Email]
FROM  [dbo].[tableU] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tableU] AS [Extent2] ON 
     ([Extent1].[Email] = [Extent2].[Email]) 
     OR (([Extent1].[Email] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[Email] IS NULL))
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused... this implies Manager is it's own table? the 'manager' is just another row in the User table.. so why do I need a Manager class?

Comment: sorry... I forgot the self link. I check a linq query allowing the materialization

Comment: I get how to do the linq query, that has never been my question - my question is how do I map the entity to itself? Especially since we're mapping on email address, which is not defined as a key...

Comment: you can't except by declaring the Email column as the key.

Comment: you may want to upvote for this [feature](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1050579-unique-constraint-i-e-candidate-key-support)

Comment: so there's no way to do what i originally asked in my question?! That's mad... Looks like I'll be going down the view route after all...  or switch to nHibernate!

Comment: may be in EF7. But actually the answer is no. To reference a "table", you must use is PK.